# How to convert bytes into a file the user can download in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django, django-file-upload

I have the bytes of a file saved in my Django database. I want users to be able to download this file.

My question is how do I convert bytes into an actual downloadable file. I know the file name, size, bytes, type and pretty much everything I need to know.

I just need to convert the bytes into a downloadable file.
How do I do this?

I don't mind sending the file bytes over to the front-end so that JavaScript could make the file available to download. Does anyone know how to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Any reason not to just write the bytes to the client as an "application/x" attachment for the user to open with the appropriate app and save if he wants to?

Comment: Well prefably I would like to know a way to turn the bytes into a file the user can download @nigel222

Comment: "_bytes of a file saved in my Django database_" please don't do that. Databases should not be used to store files. See [Should binary files be stored in the database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/should-binary-files-be-stored-in-the-database)

Comment: After researching a bit I agree with you, the only problem I have is how do I encrypt the file with Django so viruses and other malware cannot destroy my website? @AbdulAzizBarkat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check Django documentation:

[Django request-response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/)

There is a class that is FileResponse

```
FileResponse(open_file, as_attachment=False, filename='', **kwargs)
```

FileResponse is a subclass of StreamingHttpResponse optimized for binary files.

it accepts file-like object like io.BytesIO  but you have to seek() it before passing it to FileResponse.

FileResponse accepts any file-like object with binary content, for example a file open in binary mode like so:

```
   from django.http import FileResponse
   import io

   buffer = io.BytesIO(file)
   buffer.seek(0)
   response = FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='filename.foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Django documentation, this code can be used after receiving the file:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
```

If you want to save it to the database, u should just create object of your model, for example:

```
file = request.FILES["uploaded_file"]
save_file = File.objects.create(
                                name=file.name,
                                file=file
                               )
```

To download file u need a path to that file.

```
file_path = save_file.file.path
```

Comment: The problem is that there is much less freedom encrypting the file this way which means I  want to save the file as encrypted bytes string. I don't know how to convert the bytes string into a downloadable file.